# MySql stored procedure with match against

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, matching

I have a very simple stored procedure that should select some columns from 1 db table but I get an error related with the "MATCH AGAINST" syntax. Here is my procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `searchItem`(IN `Importer` VARCHAR(100), IN `Description` TEXT)
BEGIN
SELECT model, date_of_production, horsepower, importer, description FROM cars WHERE importer = Importer AND MATCH (description) AGAINST(Description) ORDER BY date_of_production ASC;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

and here is screenshot of my table
[image]

When I test the procedure it gives me an error "#1210 - Incorrect arguments to MATCH" I've tested the query out of the procedure and it works, so I'm guessing the problem is in the sintax of the procedure itself. Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html says:

> The search string must be a string value that is constant during query evaluation. This rules out, for example, a table column because that can differ for each row.

I would read this to say that you can't use your stored procedure parameter `Description` as the argument to `AGAINST`.

So you'll have to use PREPARE/EXECUTE to do this in a procedure.

---

Re comment from @Michael:

That's a good point, I hadn't noticed that the OP's table has a column whose name is identical to the name of the function parameter. You are right that this is likely to cause ambiguity.

It's always a good idea to make sure parameters for procedures and parameters have distinct names from any of your columns, to avoid this ambiguity.

Comment: I believe this is more likely to be the ambiguity of the column and variable names both being differently-cased variants of `description`/`Description` -- `MATCH (column) AGAINST (program_variable)` is valid -- the documented limitation is about things the optimizer knows can change row-by-row, but not actually including variables... but neither `MATCH (column) AGAINST (column)` nor `MATCH (program_variable) AGAINST (program_variable)` would be valid, and it almost certainly is being resolved one of these latter two ways, don't you think?